# Настроить соединение jComboBox с JList

Tags: java, sqlite, swing

На форме у меня расположено два элемента `jList` и `ComboBox` которые получают информацию из бд `SQLite`. При запуске программы я получаю пустой `jList`, хотя в `ComboBox` выбрано значение первой таблицы из бд, но при переключении между таблицами программа дополняет `jList`элементами из выбранной таблицы. А нужно что бы программа меняла содержание `jList` в соответствии c таблицей выбранной из `jComboBox`.

```
     public Connection c=null;
    public DefaultComboBoxModel dcb = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
    public DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();




   public void LoadList(){   

   // Запись из бд SQLite в Combobox
    try{
    String qry = "Select name from sqlite_master where type = 'table' ;";
    PreparedStatement pst = c.prepareStatement(qry);
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()){
        dcb.addElement(rs.getString("name")) ;

    }
    jComboBox1.setModel(dcb);
    } catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
    }



 // Выбор элемента из Combobox
  jComboBox1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ie) {
          String sa = (String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
   //Запись в jList          
          try{
    String qry = "Select * from '"+sa+"' ;";
    PreparedStatement pst = c.prepareStatement(qry);
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
    dlm.addElement(rs.getString("word"));
    }
    jList1.setModel(dlm);
    pst.close();
    rs.close();

}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}


  });

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дык перенесите просто `DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel()` перед вызовом `while(rs.next())` в `jComboBox1.addActionListener` . Т.е. создавайте его перед заполеннием и проталкиванием в `jList1`

Или вызывайте `dlm.clear()` перед вызовом `while(rs.next())` в `jComboBox1.addActionListener`

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, помогло. Но до конца проблему не решило. Осталась проблема с чтением из ComboBox при запуске приложения, т.е. я запускаю программу и получаю пустой jList до тех пор, пока не выберу таблицу из списка, вот только тогда jList заполняется. Как сделать так, что бы он заполнялся сразу при запуске. П.С. При запуске в ComboBox присутствует название первой таблицы

Comment: @Interesant вынесите все что в `ActionListener` компонента  `jComboBox` в отдельную функцию. И, соответсвенно, вызовите её и в `ActionListener` компонента  `jComboBox` и после вызова `jComboBox1.setModel(dcb)`

Comment: Хорошая идея, но вот если меня попросят удалить абсолютно все таблицы и создать новые, то мне хана. Но все равно, спасибо за хорошую идею!